# Javascript option change head style.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a relatively simple form with an option to select the theme.
What I need is javascript to view the current selected option and change the style.css file depending on its class. For example, if Dark where selected in the option it would need to reokace style.css with dark.css
Here is my select code:

```html
<option value="<?= $_SESSION['user']['theme']?>">Current</option>
<option value="volvo">Dark</option>
<option value="saab">Light</option>
<option value="mercedes">Grass</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does, or do, your `<style>` element(s) have an `id` or `class` to allow them to be found? And can you show the rendered HTML of the `<select>` element, instead of the HTML+PHP that you're currently showing? We need to see what the browser sees, your server code is, once the browser has the HTML, entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this example:

1) set css file path in option value

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ptraxc90/8/

```
<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css">
<select id="themes">
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css">Le Frog</option>
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">Start</option>
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">Smoothness</option>
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">Redmond</option>
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">Sunny</option>
</select> 
<input type="submit" value="A submit button">
```

2) as select option changes get that value and change link css file path

```
$('#themes').change(function(){
    $("#stylesheet").attr({href : $('#themes').val()});
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly!! Thank you so much. The satisfying feeling of seeing the whole site style change at a click of a button :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend changing the actual style files, your just adding another request to the page, its way more efficient to add the different styles in one file, then add a class for the different styles with javascript.

css

```
option {
    background:white
}
.dark option {
    background:black
}
```

jQuery when option is selected

```
$('form').addClass('dark');
```

or

```
$('form').toggleClass('dark');
```

Comment: That's the whole point, the whole site style needs to change. the selector is just for a preview. Once form is submitted the value is stored in session and used in the head request.